# Shortcut for cleaning project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there any shortcut for cleaning a project? Or can we create a shortcut for cleaning the project using:

> Window--> Preferences--> Java --> Editor --> Templates?

If yes ,how?

Comment: I was just asking myself this question yesterday...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To clean android project:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys (Ctrl+Shift+L)
```

in type filter text write  **`build clean`**. There you can bind the key, for ex.  **`Ctrl+Shift+L`**.

Comment: @George answer does not require key bindings

Comment: @MAC Anyway to prevent the dialogue from coming up? Here is what I am doing: (Ctrl+Shift+L+Enter). Enter closes the dialogue.

Comment: Yes, how to omit `Enter`?

Answer (score 46):

It's quite easy:

1. Press  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
2. Release <kbd>ALT</kbd>
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What OS/Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: 1. ALT + P, 2. Release ALT, 3. N, 4. Enter; Worked for me on Linux (Mint)

Comment: "When" should be "In Windows" when adding the shortcut.

Answer (score 10):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys (Ctrl+Shift+L+L)

In *type filter text*, type clean. The you will have the possible command and you can assign any short cut you want.

Comment: its not clean android project

Comment: The list have more commands, but build clean is one of them. Is the same that you have answered. So i am surprised about your comments.

Answer (score 6):

As George said, it is really easy.

Just keep an eye on underlines coming out when you hit  <kbd>ALT</kbd> .
Then if you follow these underlines, hit <kbd>P</kbd> and then <kbd>N</kbd>.

Note:
No need have to have  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  pressed down or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end.

Comment: Hey @Yannis, how'd you make those neat keyboard keys?

Comment: @ClayBanks you can find it yourself, by hitting "edit" on my post (without save an edit ofcourse!). The key is to surround the key in "kbd" tags.

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences/General/Keys look for "Build Clean".
You can assign a binding for that command.
Works for me on Mac OS X Kepler.