# Quick Keys for Code Cleanup in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

While using NetBeans, I would use Alt+Shift+f to cleanup the code.  Is there a combination like that for Eclipse to cleanup the code there?  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut for cleaning project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517028/shortcut-for-cleaning-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control+Shift+F for cleaning up your code